# Validate with arrays

Tags: php, arrays, validation

I'm trying to find a smarter way to validate my inputs with PHP. If the array finds an empty field, it has to add a new element to the array and display an error message.

So far, I haven't succeeded.

**The code behind**

```
$felter = array();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $produktnavn = $_POST['produktnavn'];
        $kategori = $_POST['kategori'];

        if( !empty( $felter ) ) {

            foreach ($felter as $felt) {
                if ($felter == '') {
                    $fejl = true;
                }
            }            

        }

        else {

            $sql = "UPDATE produkt SET produkt_navn = '$produktnavn', fk_kategori_id = '$kategori' WHERE produkt_id=$id";
            mysqli_query($db, $sql);

            echo "Produktet blev opdateret";

        }
```

**Input form**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="produktnavn" value="<?php echo $produktnavn; ?>">
```

Comment: So, is your code working or not?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Please include them in the question and **NOT** in the comments

Comment: try changing `if ($felter == '') {` to `if ($felt == '') {` because `$felter` is an array

Comment: I am not getting any errors, I don't think im targeting the input fields the right way. If there were any errors, I would have put them in the thread.

Comment: If you're checking to see if the array `$felter` is not empty, you can check by ensuring that the `count` method on that array is higher than 0, and to ensure that $felter is an array you can run `is_array($felter)` - as mentioned in earlier comment, `!empty` is an operator for strings. Lastly, you should check that your `$_POST` vars are initialized and defined, you can use `isset($_POST['produktnavn'])` as an example. Oh, and one more thing-- you're going to want to sanitize your input from any source. Never trust unchecked user submitted data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code starts with `$felter = array();` which initializes an empty array.

Then, without changing the array itself, you're checking for non-emptiness of `$felter`

```
if( !empty( $felter ) ) {
            foreach ($felter as $felt) {
                if ($felter == '') {
                    $fejl = true;
                }
            }             
        }
```

You're trying to iterate over an array that has not gotten any elements pushed into it. And the logic statement `if( !empty ($felter))` will also not work as expected either.

As a test, before the check for !empty, put something in the array with `$felter[] = 'Test word';` and then, underneath it... (if you're looking for a non-empty array, the logical checker could be `if(count($felter)) {` before iterating over the array with `foreach ($felter as $felt) { if ($felt == '')`

```
$felter = array();
$felter[] = 'Test word';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $produktnavn = $_POST['produktnavn'];
    $kategori = $_POST['kategori'];

    if( count( $felter ) ) {
            foreach ($felter as $felt) {
                if ($felt == '') {
                    $fejl = true;
                }
            }             
     }
```